# Truing to learn python and scraping sites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape a table in a site where the structure of the table is as follows:

```html
<table id="id-ofTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have so far but it is throwing an error.

```
table = soup.find('table',id='member-site-info-table')
table

rows = table.find_all("tr")

for rows in rows[1:]:
        cells = rows.find_all(['td','th'])

        cells_text = [cell.get_text(strip = True) for cell in cells]
        print(cells_text)

headers = []
for i in table.find_all('th'):
 title = i.text
 headers.append(title)

mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)
print(mydata)
print(len(mydata))


for j in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    row_data = j.find_all('td')
    print(row_data)
    row = [i.text for i in row_data]
    print(row)
    length = len(mydata)
    print(mydata)
    mydata.loc[length] = row
```

my goal is to turn "data point1" into the header and the only row will be "data point2" in the tag `<td>`. Is this something that is possible without complicating too much?

The error I am getting:

```
raise ValueError("cannot set a row with mismatched columns")

ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to parse a table in a html file to get the data into an csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken data as `html`

```
html="""<table id="id-ofTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="row">data point1</th>
<td>data point2</td>
</tr> """
```

Now you can find `th` table head for columns and rows as per `td` tag and create `df` according to data and you can get your desire output!

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
columns=[i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all("th")]
rows=[[i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all("td")]]
pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,data=rows)
```

Output:

```
    data point1 data point1 data point1 data point1
0   data point2 data point2 data point2 data point2
```

Comment: how would you address if within a <tr> tag there is `<td>
data<br>
data<br>
data
</td>` or `<td>
<ul>
<li>data</li>
<li>data </li>
</ul>
</td>` or `<td><p>data<strong>data</strong></p><p>data</p><p><strong>NovemberData</strong><p><strong>BAYdata</strong></p><ul><li>AA data</li><li>AB data</li><li>AC data</li><li>AD data</li></ul><p>DATA</p></td>`